# Can all mobile functionalities be accessed using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, mobile

I am interested in building a mobile app using JavaScript.
I was wondering if using JS will enable me use all the functionalities I need.

The app i am planning to build is for people to report when they see homeless people. The functionalities given below:

1. Whenever you open the app, you get a map.
2. The phone's location must be used to set current location on the
       map.
3. Option to report your location if you just saw a homeless person.
4. The app sets a pin on your location for all the other users to see.
5. When someone else opens the app, that user gets a map with pins
       wherever homeless people were reported, and can add a pin of his
       own.

Is this possible??

Thanks!!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow :) Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic to learn about the type of questions to ask.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in several ways. But If you are keen on using **JavaScript** along with **Native** features of mobile, your best option would be to use [React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/)